# SSIS Package Execution Error under AppId Credentials

Tags: sql, ssis

I've got a weird problem. I have a stored procedure that is kicking off my ssis packages. It gets kicked off via our scheduler system. Here is the snip-it of the stored procedure:

```
--Kickoff the package/report
IF @ReportType = 'SSIS'                     
Set @Sql = 'Exec dbo.SSIS_ExecPackage @PackageName = ''Package1.dtsx'''
--Set @Sql = 'Exec dbo.SSIS_ExecPackage @PackageName = ''' + @DeliverySsisPackageName + '.dtsx' + ''''      


--Exec the report
Exec sp_executesql @Sql
```

When I hard code the Package Name like this:

```
Set @Sql = 'Exec dbo.SSIS_ExecPackage @PackageName = ''Package1.dtsx'''
```

It works fine. But when I use the variable, like this:

```
Set @Sql = 'Exec dbo.SSIS_ExecPackage @PackageName = ''' + @DeliverySsisPackageName + '.dtsx' + ''''
```

It fails. The even weirder thing is that when I run this under my own credentials both ways work.

When I look at the ssis execution on the server, I see the attempt. So Know it's being executed. The AppId has all the appropriate rights. This is the error on the SSIS Server:

> Unable to create the type with the name 'DTS.ConnectionManagerOleDb.5'.;   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.ManagedWrapper.SetManagedObject(String assemblyName, String className)
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Interop.ProjectInterop.AddConnectionManagerFromXml(XmlNode xmlNode, IDTSEvents events)
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.ConnectionManagerItem.LoadInternal(Stream stream, IDTSEvents events)
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.ConnectionManagerItem.Load(IDTSEvents events, Stream stream)
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.ConnectionManagerItem.Load()
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Project.EnsureConnectionsAreLoaded()
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.Shared.ServerProject.LoadProject(SqlConnection connection)
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.Shared.ServerProjectLoader.GetServerProject()
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.ISServerExec.ProjectOperator.StartPackage()
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.ISServerExec.ProjectOperator.PerformOperation()

Comment: Are you positive the creds are the same? I haven't encountered any occasions where all the creds were the same and an account not have access. In saying that you may have to grant AppId execute permissions to something.

Comment: Yes.. I'm positive. My process loops thru the the packages that have due reports. If i make it so it doesn't loop it works fine.

Comment: Let me clarify: I found that the package will run regardless of how I run it (Hard coded package name, or from a variable). It was the loop that was the issue.

Comment: Hmm does it fail on the same package every time?

Comment: It fails no matter the package, if it's in the loop is atll that matters.